# Magento Shopping Options Block URLs on Homepage Just Refresh Homepage

Tags: xml, magento

I am trying to get the “shopping options” block in the left column on my homepage. When I place the code in my homepage design section it shows up perfectly, but when I click on anything (manufacturer, price, category) it just refreshes the homepage. It does not take me to the correct page.

The URL it displays when I click on a category is: example.com/?cat="CAT_ID"

I am using the same code in my catalog.xml and it seems to work fine there.
The URL when I click to refine a category is: example.com/category.html?cat="CAT_ID"

Here is the code I am using in my homepage CMS and catalog.xml

```
<!-- SHOP OPTIONS LEFT -->
  <reference name="left">
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.cat.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="catalog.cat.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.compared</alias></action>
</reference>
<!-- END SHOP OPTIONS -->
```

Any ideas on why when the code is on the homepage it just refreshes?

Here is an example of the "shopping options" in the left column:
[image]